# ¿Es gramaticalmente correcta la actual traducción de «low-pass filter» como «filtro paso bajo»?

Tags: traducción, gramática, vocabulario-técnico

En electrónica, un [*low-pass filter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) es, a grandes rasgos, un componente a través del cual solo pueden pasar las señales de baja frecuencia. De igual manera, un *high-pass filter* es un componente que solo deja pasar frecuencias altas.

En español, estos componentes se llaman «[filtro **paso bajo**](http://diccionario.raing.es/es/lema/filtro-paso-bajo)» y «[filtro **paso alto**](http://diccionario.raing.es/es/lema/filtro-paso-alto)».

Desde siempre, el uso de la expresión «paso bajo» como adjetivo de «filtro» me ha parecido un poco raro en español. Me da la sensación de que es una traducción demasiado literal. No sé explicarlo bien, pero creo que si este concepto lo hubiese ideado un hispanohablante, lo habría llamado... «filtro "bajopasante"» o algo por el estilo. Lo mismo aplica para «filtro paso alto».

**¿Tiene base gramatical traducir el "adjetivo" *low-pass* como «paso bajo»?** Y si no la tiene, **¿cuál sería una traducción más ideal?**

Comment: En el texto por Oppenheim, se tradujo como "Un filtro paso bajas" por que baja describe las frecuencias no filtradas (mas común parece ser paso bajo como en Soliman senales y sistemas continuos y discretos 2nd y wikipedia).

Comment: la pregunta y el título son ligeramente diferentes.  En el título, se pregunta si «filtro paso bajo» está bien dicho (que representa dos sustantivos yuxtapuestos) pero la pregunta en el texto principal pregunta «paso bajo» (con el adjetivo bajo aplicado al sustantivo paso en vez de a frecuencia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es curioso, porque yo juraría que estos filtros los estudié en la carrera como "filtro de paso de baja" y "de paso de alta". La explicación es que lo que se deja pasar (o no) son frecuencias, que es una palabra de género femenino. Por tanto, la expresión sería "filtro de paso de baja" para indicar que toda frecuencia baja pasa. También se podría decir "filtro de bajas frecuencias".

Buscando en Google se pueden encontrar más de 1000 resultados para "filtro de paso baja", apenas una decena para "filtro de paso de baja", y más de 16000 para "filtro de paso de bajas" (incluyendo siempre las comillas en el término de búsqueda). Para "filtro de paso bajo" se encuentran más de 120000, por lo que parece que es el término consolidado.

La explicación gramatical supongo que será por la concordancia entre el género de *alto/bajo* con el de *paso*. Visualmente se podría identificar como las [puertas del Imaginarium](https://www.google.es/search?q=puertas%20imaginarium&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=wUesQP82ejzpDM%253A%252C9wLmA5d0p_ogjM%252C_&usg=__YQ5iTPn_H8zfXJ6FBX5E7PSGeQA%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi92IzVxrvYAhUO2aQKHdm5AMIQ9QEIPDAD#imgrc=_): una grande y otra pequeña. Por la puerta pequeña (el paso bajo) solo pasan los niños (las bajas frecuencias), y por la puerta grande pasan preferentemente los adultos (las altas frecuencias). Sí, los pequeños también pueden pasar por la puerta grande, pero vamos, es para que cojáis la idea.

Comment: @walen, en los años 80 ya estaba establecida esa terminología. Y yo no he usado ninguna otra. Me resultan extrañas las expresiones "pasa baja", "filtro de paso baja", "filtro de paso de bajas".

Answer (score 1):

Yo he escuchado ambos usos. Me parece que una de las formas describe el comportamiento del filtro (filtro de paso de altas frecuencias) y la otra se enfoca en la frecuencia que el filtro realiza su acción (filtro que pasa altas frecuencias). Si miramos las versiones yuxtapuestas de ambos usos obtenemos: paso-alta y pasa-alta.

Ahora, en la yuxtaposición "paso-bajo", ¿a qué se refiere el "bajo"? Si miramos el rango auditivo del ser humano, "bajo" corresponde a aquellos sonidos más graves de la voz humana. El bajo también tiene un carácter histórico ya que una de las áreas que causó (y sigue causando) grandes avances en la teoría y uso de filtros es la transmisión de la voz humana.

Si regresamos al inglés, ***low-pass filter***, es la versión corta de ***low-frequency pass filter***. Al traducir esto, sería **filtro de paso de baja frecuencia**. Esto separa la acción de filtro (el dejar pasar) del objeto que deja pasar. O sea un "paso-baja" o un "paso-alta".

Answer (score -1):

Actualmente se utilizan las terminologías "pasa baja", "pasa alta", "pasa banda" y "rechaza-banda". Son las que siempre he oído.

Answer (score -1):

En mi experiencia (ingeniero, Argentina), es "**filtro pasa bajo/alto**" o "[pasa bajos/altos](http://musiki.org.ar/Filtro_pasa_bajos_(LPF))".